# Operator '+' is not defined for type 'integer' and type 'dbnull'

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, operators, nul, custom-data-type

I'm try to calculate total column of data grid view, number data type in Oracle, data grid view column with null value.....

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
For line As Integer = 0 To dgvAccDetail.RowCount - 1

    X = X + dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value

    y = y + dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value

Next
TXTVoucherDTotal.Text = X
txtvoucherCtotal.Text = y
```

but get msg:

> operator '+' is not defined for type 'integer' and type 'dbnull'

..... please tell me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: What do you want to happen for the items which have been returned as NULL from the database? Perhaps the SQL query needs to be adjusted to not select rows with NULLs.

Comment: Check if dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value or dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value are equal to dbNull

Comment: data gird view have two column debit and credit ,... i just need to tile sum of both column that why im doing this

Comment: @EjazSarwar One of them (or both) is NULL. What do you want to do with the NULL? Should it be regarded as 0, or does it mean that the row is invalid and so the other column should not be used either?

Comment: i want my code consider null value (empty cell) as 0,

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you are treating "DBNull" as 0:

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
For line As Integer = 0 To dgvAccDetail.RowCount - 1

    X = X + If(IsDBNull(dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value),0,dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value)

    y = y + If(IsDBNull(dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value),0,dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value)

Next
TXTVoucherDTotal.Text = X.tostring
txtvoucherCtotal.Text = y.tostring
```

EDIT: To avoid an exception being thrown in the case that  the value in the cells is not an integer (instead it will count as 0) - as pointed out by Ctznkane525 in the comments.

```
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    For line As Integer = 0 To dgvAccDetail.RowCount - 1

        If dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells.Count >= 5 AndAlso TypeOf dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value Is Integer Then
            X = X + DirectCast(dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(4).Value, Integer)
        End If

        If dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells.Count >= 6 AndAlso TypeOf dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value Is Integer Then
            y = y + DirectCast(dgvAccDetail.Rows(line).Cells(5).Value, Integer)
        End If

    Next

    TXTVoucherDTotal.Text = X.ToString
    txtvoucherCtotal.Text = y.ToString
```

Comment: type casting issue here?

Comment: @Ctznkane525  Ah. Oops. Thanks, Good spot. I actually didn&amp;amp;#39;t have option strict on or off as I quickly free hand typed it, but I should still have thought of that. My apologies. I will update my answer when I am next at my computer.